# cake console baking on different datasource (pluguin array)

Tags: arrays, cakephp, plugins, datasource

I ve installed datasource plugin Array. It do NOT use db tables as source of data. Its an array (source). When i try to bake using cake bake (or something) it doesnt recognize the array source used, only the tables of my database.

I would like to bake all the crud actions as done for datasource database tables as my array datasource. how can i acomplish that ?

ty advance

Comment: why are you not just using a real table then? that would make bake pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

After you setup your DataSources. If you running the bake command from your root directory where you can see `bin` folder.

This will give you list of tables

```
sudo bin/cake bake.bake model --connection OTHER_DATABASE_NAME
```

Let's say we want to bake for `Users` table

Bake a model

```
sudo bin/cake bake.bake model TABLE_NAME --connection OTHER_DATABASE_NAME
```

---

In cakephp 3.x

If you want to do it manually you can create your Entity class and Table class as normal. and then in UsersTable.php add this function:

```
public static function defaultConnectionName()
    {
        return 'OTHER_DATABASE_NAME';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Cake Bake ( and i think other console commands ) cake will look at the default value in your DATABASE_CONFIG ***unless*** you use the "-c" option. It lets you choose a different data connection. You probably default set to your database and a different one for the array datasource.

Answer (score 0):

try edit yout file app.php:

```
    'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'aws.amazon-br.service',
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'passaword',
        'database' => 'wp_my_site',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ],

    /**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'my_system_db' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostgator.dbsource.manager',
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'my_systen',
        'password' => 'secret_password',
        'database' => 'my_system',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

After saving the app.php file, go to yout pronpt and use the bake command this format:

> cake bake all name_table -c name_your_connect

Example:

> cake bake all users -c my_system_db